# How to get current dom element in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angularjs, just like many other developer, I was jquery developer. Now I have a question about directive.
example: if i have a directive like this:

```
app.directive('mydiv',function(){
     return{
     restrict:'AE',
     template:'<div><ul><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul></div>', //of course in real case it will be use ng-repeat
     link:function(scope,element,attr){

     }
}               
})
```

the confuse I have is,if I need to access any

element,in jquery we can use $(this), how can we do it with angular way? Can I do like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {    //when hover show the delete icon for each msg and apply highlight class to it.
                element.find('li').hover(
                        function(){
                            $(this).addClass('highlight');
                            scope.deleteicon=true;
                        },
                        function(){
                            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
                            scope.deleteicon=false;
                        });                 
        }
```

Comment: In your link function you have the parameter injected called "element" which will be a jqLite element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the element as the 1st argument (`element` argument in your case) of the link function itself. If you are using jquery with angular and loading jquery before angular the element` will be wrapped in jquery wrapper, i.e it will be a jquery object. If not angular uses a lighter subset of jquery called jqlite. It only provided a minimal functionality.

See [element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) for details.

Instead of binding `hover` event manually you should use angular event binding and use `ng-class` instead of add/remove class. That way you perform things angular way and you do not need to manually invoke digest cycle via `scope.$apply()` for DOM updates with respect to scope updates (Which you need to do in the hover pseudo event in your example to reflect DOM updates based on scope property `deleteicon`).

An example implementation of your directive will look like this. There are numerous ways you can do this using angular built-in directives itself.

```
.directive('mydiv',function(){
     return {
     restrict:'AE',
     scope:{items:"="}, //<-- data bound from parent scope via attribute
     template:'<div><ul><li ng-mouseenter="toggleClass(true)" ng-mouseleave="toggleClass(false)" ng-class="{'highlight': action.deleteicon}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li></ul></div>', //of course in real case it will be use ng-repeat
     link:function(scope,element,attr){
        scope.action = {deleteicon :true};
        scope.toggleClass = function(show){
             scope.action.deleteicon = show;
        }
     }
   }               
});
```

- `scope:{items:"="},` sets up 2 way binding if you wish to bind the data from the parent scope via attribute.
- Instead of repeating `li` use a data model, say an array of items and use `ng-repeat` instead of duplicating the tag (unless you need to do it for sure). ex:- `ng-repeat="item in items"`
- Use angular event bindings instead of binding the events manually, hover is nothing but nouseenter/mouseleave. So you can use respective angular directives and bind a function on the scope. i.e `ng-mouseenter="toggleClass(true)" ng-mouseleave="toggleClass(false)"`.
- Use `ng-class` bound to a scope variable to toggle the class. Let angular manage DOM manipulation for toggling the css class on the element. You just worry about the *data being bound*. i.e `ng-class="{'highlight': action.deleteicon}"`

You can find official documentation on angular built in directives/components.

Comment: Thank you for your information!But if I need to do other action on each <li> for example: <li>{{items.name}}<span>delete</span></li> when I click delete(span) I need to delete whole li,actually it will fire a ajax call. all I need to do is bind delete function into <span>? like: <span ng-click='deletecurrentli('items.name')'> of course I need to define delete function in controller. the items.name I pass into function is refer to current li?

Comment: Just bind an ng-click to span and pass the item and split it out of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you used `hover`, but, you can use the [MouseOver Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover).

As the following example:

```
<li ng-mouseover="high = true" ng-class="{'highlight':high}">Content</li>
```

Comment: wouldn't you need some sort of mouse out thing too?

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this plkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fHUSrQiQdu3KSWFFGfIC)

Markup:

```
<div class="row" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-push-3">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-init="myclass='hide'" ng-repeat="item in items"
                    ng-mouseenter="myclass = 'show'" ng-mouseleave="myclass='hide'">
                    <span>{{item}}</span>
                    <span ng-class="'pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-edit '+myclass"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
            .controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.items = ['abc', 'xyz', 'klm'];
            });
```